# Creating a asyemmtric key from an existing assembly

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, .net-assembly

I have an assembly named [Testing.Framework.sql] in a Testing database. I do not have the DLL or file for the assembly.

I need to make an asymmetric key from it and login to grant it unsafe assembly status.

I tried this:

```
USE master;
GO  

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY TestingProjectKey FROM ASSEMBLY [Testing].[Testing.Framework.SQL]
-- CREATE LOGIN TestingProjectLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY TestingProjectKey ;  
-- GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO TestingProjectLogin ;
-- GO
```

The key needs to be run in master but I get errors trying to access the assembly which is in the Testing db.  I tried [Testing][Testing.Framework.SQL] to but get syntax errors.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Try getting the name of the assembly directly from sql: 
select * from sys.assembly_modules

Comment: It only gives me assembly id and class like assembly class: TestingProject.Framework.SQL.Encryption

Comment: I also had to run it from the testing db and not from master

Comment: Ack. Sorry, sys.assemblies is the correct view. Not sure referencing it from a different database is supported. Per: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2de8f961-5ee1-40a0-b1d5-cb9b3c01c24b/is-it-possible-to-create-asymmetric-key-from-assembly-in-another-database?forum=sqlnetfx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create the assembly in master using the UI: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/74377/

Once you've created the key, you can drop the assembly out of master.